How can I make the image clear and fine even I zoom in and zoom out?
enter image description here - Original position of image
enter image description here- Zoom in image
How can I make text and words readable, clear, good quality image?
Source code:
   private Pane createPagePane(int pageIndex, PDDocument document, PDFRenderer renderer, AnchorPane anchorPane) throws IOException {
    PDPage page = document.getPage(pageIndex);
    PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
    boolean isLandscape = pageSize.getWidth() > pageSize.getHeight();

    double widthToFit = anchorPane.getPrefWidth();
    double heightToFit = anchorPane.getPrefHeight();

    double scaleFactor = isLandscape ? Math.min(widthToFit / pageSize.getWidth(), heightToFit / pageSize.getHeight())
            : Math.min(heightToFit / pageSize.getWidth(), widthToFit / pageSize.getHeight());

    int targetWidth = (int) (pageSize.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
    int targetHeight = (int) (pageSize.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = renderer.renderImage(pageIndex, (float) scaleFactor, ImageType.RGB);


    BufferedImage backgroundImage = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = backgroundImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    g2d.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(backgroundImage, null);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(fxImage);

    imageView.setFitWidth(targetWidth);
    imageView.setFitHeight(targetHeight);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setSmooth(true);
    imageView.setCache(true);

    Pane pagePane = new Pane(imageView);
    pagePane.setPrefSize(targetWidth, targetHeight);

    pagePane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        pagePane.getStyleClass().add("selected-pane");
    });

    rectMouseInteraction(pagePane, document, pageIndex, scaleFactor);

    return pagePane;
}

What I am expecting is like this outcome:
enter image description here - This was also converted and created via Buffered image.
I want mine to be like this quality even I zoom in the image.

If your panel contain only text, you should use vector font instead of an image.

Scaling the image to printing size results in a smaller image, which is why you are losing sharpness and detail.  Your program should not scale the image to the page size, until the program is actually printing the page.
While viewing the page on the screen, pass 1 as the scale, so it is rendered with maximum detail.  Then fit it using BackgroundSize.contain, so it will scale to fit the containing Pane’s size:
PDPage page = document.getPage(pageIndex);

BufferedImage bufferedImage = renderer.renderImage(pageIndex, 1, ImageType.RGB);

Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);

Pane pagePane = new Pane();

BackgroundSize size =
    new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO,
        false, false, true, false);

pagePage.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(fxImage,
    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
    null, size)));

